# Do non-Medium creatures use differently-sized splash weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, creature-size, alchemy

Because I wanted it to have some ability to make area attacks, I was considering arming with flasks of [alchemist's fire](http://dndsrd.net/goodsAndServices.html#alchemists-fire) (*Player's Handbook* 128) (20 gp; 1 lb.) a [fire giant](http://dndsrd.net/monstersG.html#fire-giant) (*Monster Manual* 121–2). However, it struck me as odd that a fire giant would use the same flask of alchemist's fire that a puny dwarf would use. By the same token, pity the Tiny [grig](http://dndsrd.net/monstersS.html#grig) (235) that has a light load of just 8 lbs. that must laboriously haul to the battlefield that same 1-lb. flask.

Are splash weapons like other weapons that scale in price, weight, and damage according to their size? And, if so, what effect does this scaling have on such weapons' splash radii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not scale in cost, weight, damage or size.

Rationale: None of the "Special Substances And Items" (from http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/goodsAndServices.htm) have a size markup on them.  An arguement could be made nowhere in that table does however just above in "Adventuring Gear" there is and this includes vial and flask.  I see no reason or basis that the alchemical makeup for the contents of a "medium" flask would change.

PS: I agree it does seem silly=)

Comment: Enter the portable hole full of... something. There are also those beads of water I mentioned somewhere else around here as an expensive option. Ah, *Dust of Dryness* it was.

Comment: Silly from a practical viewpoint, but nightmarish from a rules viewpoint to do it any other way.  A flask of alchemist's fire / acid / holy water does 1 point of splash damage in a 5 foot radius - how do you change this for a Small or Tiny flask?  And then there are game balance issues for low level parties if Large flasks are allowed that do more damage than available spells...